# Nestjs controller not getting called from angular service file

Tags: angular, oauth, nestjs

I am trying to create a nestjs controller and call it from angular service file.
Below is my old code structure

```
--src
  --app
  server.module
  server.controller
  server.ts
```

Server.controller has 2 api which is working

Below is my new code structure

```
--src
  --app
    angular.service
  --root
    root.module
    server.controller
    server.module
  --server
    --api
      new.controller
      new.service
      new.module
    --oauth
  server.ts
```

new.controller is the nestjs controller that I created and have 1get and 1post endpoint.

When I try to call it from "angular.service", it is not getting called but the flow is going inside @all method which is in server.controller.

When I comment @all and try to call newly created endpoint, it is working. But @all is mandatory for me.

**Note:** I create new.controller, new.service and new.module using angular commands and changed it to nestjs supported one.

I guess I am missing some connectivity or something minute. Can someone help in fixing this and I am new to nestjs.

I checked all the connections in module files
Tried having the new endpoint in server.contoller but the app is getting crashed while running.

Comment: Can you show the NestJS controller in use?